# Correct way to cancel SSE stream created with WebFlux

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-webflux

First of all, full running code example (both client and server) is available here: https://github.com/kklepacz/webflux-cancel-subscription

Case description:

I have legacy system that produces data (I mocked it with `SampleEmitter` in my github example. I can provide listener to it and it will be notified when new data arrives. I want to "translate" these listener calls into stream of data. This stream need to be infinite one (there will be new values as long as system is working). To be precise it need to be hot source also (following the `Reactor` project terminology) so whenever someone will subscribe, he will receive only current values.

Here how translation looks like:

```
class ReactiveRepoImpl implements ReactiveRepo {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReactiveRepoImpl.class);
private final UnicastProcessor<MyObject> hotProcessor = UnicastProcessor.create();
private final FluxSink<MyObject> fluxSink = hotProcessor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);
private final Flux<MyObject> hotFlux = hotProcessor.publish().autoConnect();

@Override
public void save(MyObject elem) {
    fluxSink.next(elem);
}

@Override
public Flux<MyObject> findAll() {
    return hotFlux;
}
}
```

So at this point I can expose it via `RouterFunctions` like this:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction routerFunction(ReactiveRepo repo) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/objects"), serverRequest -> {
        log.info("Subscribing for GET /objects");
        return ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .body(repo.findAll(), MyObject.class);
    });
}
```

As you can see I'm producing Server Side-Events here.

Now lets consume it:

```
 WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080")
                .get()
                .uri("/objects")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(MyObject.class)
                .subscribe(n -> log.info("Next: {}", n.getId()),
                        e -> log.error("Error: {}", e),
                        () -> log.info("Completed"));
```

The problem is: 
When I will kill client or call `Disposable.dispose()` I'm receiving following error in server application:

```
2018-03-20 12:00:50.926 ERROR 11944 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : Unhandled failure: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine, response already set (status=200)
2018-03-20 12:00:50.941 ERROR 11944 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : Handling completed with error

java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:418) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler$PublisherSender.onComplete(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:535) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:184) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:80) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart.subscribe(FluxContextStart.java:49) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6873) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.drain(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:461) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.flush(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:191) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1129) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1070) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_144]

2018-03-20 12:00:50.957 ERROR 11944 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations    : [HttpServer] Error processing connection. Requesting close the channel

java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:418) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler$PublisherSender.onComplete(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:535) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:122) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:245) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:184) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:80) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:59) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart.subscribe(FluxContextStart.java:49) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6873) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.drain(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:461) [reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.flush(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:191) [reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1129) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1070) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

How can I avoid it? What is a correct way to create such hot source stream and handle multiple clients disconnections/stream cancellation and connections/subscriptions properly?

To give you full picture why I need such feature - I have a web application with tabs. On one tab I show all data received from my server. When I switch tab, I dont want my stream to continue, I want to unsubscribe and subscribe again when I will come back to this tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR;**

`dispose()` is a correct way to unsubscribe from a stream.

**Full answer:**

I couldn't find answer over the internet so I've asked source - Spring team. 
Here is a JIRA I've created: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16688

So, according to comments there, stacktrace above is a result of not covered Windows enviroment specific exceptions while working with `Undertow`, `Tomcat` and `Netty`. They should not occur on Linux/Unix or when using `Jetty`. Spring team will fine tune this one in next releases - probably `5.0.6` and/or `5.1 RC1` according to JIRA.